# How to escape '&' symbol of Text in SQL WHERE Clause?

Tags: java, sql, oracle10g

How to escape '&' dynamically in a text in WHERE clause in SQL. My DB is Oracle. I am trying as below:

```
public  List getBookingList( String searchText ){

String sql= "  SELECT c.name  FROM customer c  WHERE c.name like ? " ;

List params = new ArrayList();    
params.add("%"+searchText+"%");  
// "searchText" may contain "&",Ex: A&B Beverage Ltd. How to search with it.

return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,params.toArray());

}
```

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` and have a look for posts about `SQL injection`.

Comment: I have edited the code snippet. Two question marks were written wrongly here. It should be one .

Comment: `&` does not need to be "escaped"

Comment: Do u think so? can u show me screenshot of the executed query?